# Java WindowListener actions Closing/Opened

Tags: java, file, exception, stream, listener

So, i am trying to save the current state of the application uppon the user closing the application and when the application reopens, the data is read from a serialized file, saved on the drive.

I have to somehow check if there is such a file located in the directory and if there is, read from it, if not (FileNotFOundException), the app should normally start withou any data in it and then save it (i would in this case, delete the file manually).

This is my listener class, that i have defined (it throws filenotfound now that i have deleted the file):

```
class ShraniPovrni implements WindowListener {

    private ArrayList<TovornaLadja> seznamLadij;

    public ShraniPovrni(ArrayList<TovornaLadja> seznamLadij) {
        this.seznamLadij = seznamLadij;
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Janezek.ser")));
            oos.writeObject(seznamLadij);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Tezave " + ex.toString() + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("Janezek.ser")));
            seznamLadij = (ArrayList<TovornaLadja>) oos.readObject();
            oos.close();
            System.out.println(seznamLadij);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what actually do you want to ask?

Comment: how do i chech if file exits and then read from it and if it doesnt how do i make it not catch the exception but to just ignore it and "start fresh" adn then create the new file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("Janezek.ser")));
        seznamLadij = (ArrayList<TovornaLadja>) oos.readObject();
        oos.close();
        System.out.println(seznamLadij);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

to

```
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    try {
        if(new File("Janezek.ser").exists()) {
            ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("Janezek.ser")));
            seznamLadij = (ArrayList<TovornaLadja>) oos.readObject();
            oos.close();
            System.out.println(seznamLadij);
        }
        else {
            //No file is there, start fresh
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```